# Align items to the right within a flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and this CSS class to vertically align my items:

```css
.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.vertical-align > [class^="col-"],
.vertical-align > [class*=" col-"] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

With this, all this content is aligned to the left. How can I align, for example, the list (ul> li) to the right? Nothing I've tried is working.

Here is a working demo:

```css
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.vertical-align > [class^="col-"],
.vertical-align > [class*=" col-"] {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/120x50" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #ffccff;">
            <div class="catergorias">
                <ul class="list-inline categorias_topo">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">Categoria 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">Categoria 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">Categoria 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">Categoria 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
            BUSCA
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xcottg08/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `justify-content: flex-end;` instead of `justify-content:flex-start` to justify content to the right side.

You must specify it within these rules

```
.vertical-align > [class^="col-"],
.vertical-align > [class*=" col-"] {
```

However, I would create a new class like `.vertical-align-right` and one extra class to the container with list (the div above .catergorias with class .col-md-6), thus the code would look as follow:

```
.vertical-align-right > .list,
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```